# How do I get Firebase Functions Emulator working on GitHub?

Tags: python, firebase, github, continuous-integration, firebase-tools

I have a suite of Python integration tests that use the Firebase Emulator. In GitHub Actions, I have `firebase emulators:start -P demo-test & sleep 10`, followed by some initial tests to check the emulated Firestore. These initial tests pass.

However, when the suite moves to those tests that call the Functions, the `curl localhost:8080/.../` calls - that work locally - return 404 errors on the GHA host. For what it's worth, I *did* set up the `venv` - that the emulators use locally - on the GHA host. Moreover, there are no errors in the `emulators:start` stage indicating a failure to load functions. That said, there are no messages therein indicating the functions *did* load. Typically I see `... loaded functions: my_func1, my_func2` on stdout, but on GHA they are absent.

To me, this means that:

- At least the Firestore and Functions emulators start successfully.
- But somehow the configuration that allows the emulator to find my functions hasn't translated from workstation to GHA.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

---

I tried running the GHA suite.
It runs fine until it hits the integration tests that exercise Functions.
I expected those to pass as they do locally.
In reality they fail.

Comment: This may just be a race condition, in that on GHA host it takes substantially longer to start up emulators than it does on my local host. Especially considering the Python runtime will have to compile to pycache. for the first time for a hefty package...

I'm using now `emulators:exec` instead of `emulators:start` and will report back.

Answer (score 0):

It was a race condition after all. For those else looking: use `firebase:exec 'cd ../ && echo "look ma I'm testing" && make test'` rather than the `firebase:start & sleep 10`. Doh!